# Does $P \circ P =P$ and $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ imply $P$ is linear?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, idempotents

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $P:H \to H$. Suppose that
>
> - $P \circ P =P$
> - $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ for all $(x,y) \in H^2.$
>
> I would like to ask if $P$ is linear.

I tried some functions such as absolute value, identity, and constant. But none of them satisfy the second condition.

Please don't give me the proof, in case this statement is correct. I would like to give it a shot by myself.

Comment: Did you try to prove linearity by definition?

Comment: @SahibaArora I tried $y = \alpha x$ and got stuck after $\langle \alpha P x - P \alpha x, x  \rangle=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second condition alone is sufficient to get linearity.

Hint:

> The right-hand side is linear in $x$, hence the left-hand side is also linear in $x$.

Comment: Btw: One this second condition also implies that $P$ is bounded. This is a little bit harder to show (use Banach-Steinhaus or the closed graph theorem).

Comment: I've not read your solution yet. From this Wikipedia [link](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Self-adjoint_operator#/overview), I get "In mathematics, a self-adjoint operator (or Hermitian operator) on a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$ with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is a **linear** map $A$ (from $V$ to itself) that is its own **adjoint**:$\langle A v, w\rangle=\langle v, A w\rangle$ for all vectors $v$ and $w$". I wonder if self-adjoint implies linear, then why the link said "linear map $A$ (from $V$ to itself) that is its own adjoint". Is it redundant?

Comment: @LAD: Yes, it is somehow redundant. Maybe the reason is, that the adjoint is only defined for linear operators.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, you don't need $P \circ P=P.$

**Hint:** Show $$\langle P(ax_1+x_2),y\rangle=\langle aP(x_1)+P(x_2),y\rangle$$ for every $y \in H$ using the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

After many days of intermittent thoughts, I have come up with my own proof.

1. $P(\alpha x) = \alpha Px$ for all $(\alpha,x) \in \mathbb R \times H$

It suffices to show that $\langle P(\alpha x) - \alpha Px, y \rangle = 0$ for all $y \in H$. This is equivalent to $\langle P(\alpha x) , y \rangle = \langle \alpha Px, y \rangle = \alpha\langle  Px, y \rangle$. This is actually true because $\langle P(\alpha x) , y \rangle = \langle \alpha x , Py \rangle = \alpha \langle  x , Py \rangle = \alpha\langle  Px, y \rangle$.

1. $P( x + y) =Px + Py$ for all $(x,y) \in H^2$

It suffices to show that $\langle P( x + y) - Px - Py,z \rangle = 0$ for all $z \in H$. This is equivalent to $\langle P( x + y), z  \rangle = \langle Px + Py,z \rangle$. This is actually true because $\langle P( x + y), z  \rangle = \langle x + y, P z  \rangle = \langle x, P z  \rangle + \langle y, P z  \rangle = \langle Px,  z  \rangle + \langle Py,  z  \rangle= \langle Px + Py,z \rangle$.