# Is self-adjoint operator necessarily linear?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $(H, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $P: H \to H$. In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3675911/368425), @gerw said that if $$\forall (x,y) \in H^2:\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle,$$ then $P$ is linear. Because I'm trying to prove it by myself, I've not read his/her solution.

On the other hand, From this Wikipedia [link](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Self-adjoint_operator) about self-adjoint operator,

> In mathematics, a self-adjoint operator (or Hermitian operator) on a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$ with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is a **linear** map $A$ (from $V$ to itself) that is its own **adjoint**:$\langle A v, w\rangle=\langle v, A w\rangle$ for all vectors $v$ and $w$.

From the paragraph, I got that self-adjoint operator is not necessarily linear. If it was, they would not said "**linear** map $A$ that is its own **adjoint**". Could you please reconcile this difference?

Comment: @IsaacRen you meant $\forall (x,y) \in H^2:\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ does not necessarily imply $P$ is linear?

Comment: The definition of "adjoint" only applies to linear operators.

Comment: No, my first comment (which I deleted) literally repeats what you said in your question, so I deleted it.

Comment: @IsaacRen Let's not say about adjoint operator. Do you think $\forall (x,y) \in H^2:\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ implies $P$ is linear?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Let me think a little more...

Comment: I think [Sahiba Arora's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3675919/415180) is a good hint. Reminder: if $\langle z,y\rangle=0$ for all $y$, what can you say about $z$?

Comment: Thank you so much @IsaacRen! OhI got it. $\forall (x,y) \in H^2:\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ implies $P$ is linear, but not necessarily the converse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my bad. I got it :)

We have $\forall (x,y) \in H^2:\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ implies $P$ is linear, but the converse is not necessarily true.